# jenkins powershell plugin url encoding

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to fetch gitlab project info using [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding). Below powershell script works perfectly fine in powershell ise

```
$projects = Invoke-WebRequest https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/namespace%2fproject
```

But when using same script in jenkins powershell plugin, i always get error 404 Not found. I dont know if its an issue with url encoding or powershell script encoding.

I have tried below jenkins command with and without encoding

```
powershell (script:'''
     $project = Invoke-WebRequest 
     https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/namespace%2fproject
     echo $project
''', encoding: 'UTF-8', returnStdout: true)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your project is not public or requires authentication. Go to your account setting and then Access Token. Generate a new token, and then add it to your request header:

```
$gitUrl = "https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects/namespace%2fproject"

$head =  @{'PRIVATE-TOKEN'= 'YourTokenHere'; 'Content-Type'='application/json'} 

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $gitUrl -headers $head
```

Also check Invoke-RestMethod, it will parse the response into psobject (very handy sometimes)

Comment: I didnt mentioned authentication part in question but i am passing private-token both in powershell ise as well as in jenkins powershell script.

Comment: Ok. Maybe try to print url from jenkins to make sure it's not special characters issue. Also do you get any output if just hitting https://gitlab.mycompany.com/api/v4/projects ?

Comment: yeah i  echo'd uri in console and its looks fine and when i click the url, it shows right output in browser